# Kendo UI Sprite.png displaying in desktop but not displaying in tab(all browsers)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, css, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdpV1.png)I am using kendo UI for my project.while using this for dropdowns&datepicker icons displaying in desktop but its not working for tab.i changed path also.we are using .net mvc.This is desktop screen shot attached for tab dropdown and date piker icons not showing

Comment: Welcome, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Upload some photos of the problem and add the relevant code (to your question).

Comment: My assumption is that "tab" signifies a "tablet". Most probably, you are missing the retina sprite image. Its name is `sprite_2x.png` and it should be available in the same folder as 'sprite.png'

Comment: Hi dimodi Thank you so much,i missed it great job.Arendax tnq

Comment: Good, I will post it as an answer then, so you can mark it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that "tab" signifies a "tablet". Most probably, you are missing the retina sprite image. Its name is `sprite_2x.png` and it should be available in the same folder as `sprite.png`.